# I want to model an emoji

Tags: modeling

I want to model this particular emoji. I have done the mouth and the teeth,[image: the emoji] but I have no idea how to do the eyes.

Comment: Hello how does your current topology look like? maybe even share your file?

Comment: I would say use a scaled cylinder to Intersect (Knife) the shape into the sphere, delete the cylinder, select the faces inside the ovals, and extrude inward.